# Liferay LDAP integration, password storage

Tags: ldap, liferay, liferay-6, ntlm, cas

If Liferay is configured with LDAP, Liferay imports the users and password from LDAP AD. Is there a way to avoid the password storage in the liferay database?

Any help related to avoiding the password getting populated in liferay database would be useful to me.

thanks in advance

Lokesh

Comment: have you enabled ldap authentication by setting this property, ldap.auth.enabled=true. If you have set this property then liferay will authenticate against ldap and dont import password on synchronization

Answer (score 1):

Try setting below property in portal.properties/portal-ext.properties,

```
#Set this to false if the portal does not import LDAP user's password;
ldap.import.user.password.enabled=true
```

By setting above property, user's password will not be imported when synchronization

Comment: This worked for me, but it is taking the default password as test. And I am unable to authenticate with my Active Directory id.  As the default password stored in liferay is "test".

Comment: Yes I have tried with this property, but still it is importing with the default password.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was supposed to be supported in 6.1, but It was [buggy](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13554008).
there was a [Liferay blog entry](http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/6583930) on that feature, it never worked for me, and apparently, now this article is down.

If I remember correctly, you had to play with 3 or 4 properties. I think they were
ldap.import.user.password.enabled, ldap.import.user.password.autogenerate , and ldap.import.user.password.default

these values were not independent, but a combination of them would create a different LDAP behavior, and a few of these combinations had a practical meaning.

please make sure to check your liferay version. Since version 6.0, a lot of LDAP features and bugs are introduced, and each version has a different LDAP auth mechanism. I've checked the source on misc versions (6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.2.0), trying to create a stable patch, and each time I can see a major difference in the implementation. AFAIK, no version is 100% working

You might be lucky to post in Liferay forum and get help from Jonas Yuan, he's very helpful and sometimes even provides patches

Answer (score -1):

We've achieved two authentication types into LR when we've insert a login portlet into starting page. 
The no-LDAP users must have a database password and they have to logging across the portlet, but the other users must be identified by dockbar "access" system. Also, the LDAP auth must be enabled but not required.
We don't have had configure an extra in portal-ext.properties.
I hope help you. Regards.